# Jquery disable link on pseudo element in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, toggle, dropdown

In bootstrap **(4.0)** i added link href to dropdown menu element with this code:

Html:

```
<ul id="menu-header-menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="menu-item" class="nav-item">
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Home</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    content: "\f107";
    font-family: fontawesome;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 53px;    
    top: 2px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #bdbdbd
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() { 
    var location = $(this).attr('href'); window.location.href = location; return false; 
});
```

But the problem is, i can't toggle dropdown. Because when i click **.dropdown-toggle::after** it goes to link.

I want, if i click **.dropdown-toggle** go to url. But if i click **.dropdown-toggle::after** don't go. Just toggle dropdown.

Comment: Could you post the HTML you're using, and your Bootstrap version?

Comment: Edited post! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, double-checking Bootstrap docs, I think your best case is to use an input group as documented [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#split-button-dropdowns).

I got something very similar to yours working in Codepen, although you might want to alter the padding. No need for the ::after / FA either.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul id="menu-header-menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li id="menu-item" class="nav-item">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-link pr-0">Action</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So i need a <button> near the <a> element. It is hard to make it in wordpress.

Comment: You'd need an extra div for the dropdown itself anyway I believe. How are you adding this to WP?

Comment: I need a new walker class :) and i can put a new div near the all dropdown items. But what click function i must set for toggle dropdown?
for example i added **<span class="dd-toggler"></span>** near the <a> what function i must do?

Comment: No function needed. Just make sure you're including the Bootstrap javascript files.